# Synchronous insertion or increment for an array of items

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to JavaScript and have finally wrapped my head around asynchronous programming. So, while I can tell why I am having this problem, I can't really seem to find a workaround...

I have an array of strings ... ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
I am trying to add it to a mongo database in the format {word : count}

```
array.forEach(callback)

function callback(w) {
    collection.find({"word":w}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (result.length == 0) {
            //This means it's a new word
            collection.insert({"word":w, "count":1}, function(err, res) {});
        } else if (result.length == 1) {
            //Word already exists in database
            collection.update(....)
        }
    });
}
```

But a new word is inserted every time, the count is never updated. 
It's happening because of the asynchronous way it's implemented.

Ideally, I would want to take a word, check if it exists, insert/update and then look at the next word.
But I'm not sure how to do that.

I don't really expect to do it "synchronously", just the idea is similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want ["upserts"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) instead. That is basically a "find or create" in one operation. You also want a way of handling the "loop" in a way that respects the callback response of the "write" operation before looping. But it's probably reasonable to just handle that with "Bulk" operations, so that the actual "write" and "response" happens only once:

```js
collection.bulkWrite(
    array.map(function(w) {
        return {
           "updateOne": {
              "filter": { "word": w },
              "update": {
                  "$inc": { "count": 1 }
              },
              "upsert": true
           }
        }
    }),
    function(err,result) {
       // result contains BulkWriteResponse
    }
)
```

The [`$inc`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator handles the actual increment, and since this is an "upsert", then if no matching document is found to the "filter" then a new document is created. Otherwise the existing one is updated and "incremented".

In a "larger" context you would ideally read from a "stream" and build a reasonable size "batch" of "Bulk" operations for [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite). However if you just have a reasonable sized array already then there is nothing wrong with the single "in-line" context as shown.

The only thing that is "async" here is the actual [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) call, so in this context there is only **one** point where you need to wait for the response, rather than waiting for each individual operation.

There are other ways to respect the "callback" of each "write" in an "async loop", but for this particular context it is likely most suitably handled by the single [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) call, with a "batch" of "upsert" instructions.

Comment: Thanks Neil! Like I said, I'm new to JS and Mongo, so I'll have to try it out and play around with it.
Appreciate the help!